# Is there a PDF reader that formats for mobile screens?

Tags: iphone, pdf

Trying to read PDF on a mobile screen is a pain, be it iBooks or Adobe Reader. Neither of the apps properly format the content for reading on the iPhone. I was wondering if there is a "Reader" feature, similar to Safari's reading feature, on a PDF reading application that with a tap renders the content perfectly viewable on the tiny mobile screen.

If there is no such application then I would like to know how I can convert a PDF into any other format that would allow me to format the contents better for viewing on the iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

PDF files are popular precisely **because** the formatting is fixed. A PDF author can be sure that their document looks the same on any device that displays it. So I'm afraid you're asking for a feature that goes against one of the basic premises of the format.

That said, some PDFs have a text-only layer that can be displayed directly. On an iPhone, I'd recommend [Goodreader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html) for this. It will display the formatted PDF, then you can click to display the text-only version. That version may be bigger and more legible for you.

Having a text layer depends on the author of the PDF, but I would think Goodreader may be a step in the right direction for you.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Kindle for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kindle-read-books-magazines/id302584613?mt=8) can meet your requirement.
You only need to send PDF documents to your Kindle by e-mailing the PDF to to your Send-to-Kindle e-mail address. If you want to convert the PDF to another format，put the word "convert" in the subject line.
In this way, you can get a better experience to read PDF on the iOS.

[Send to Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/?docId=1000778781) just recently came out. It allows you to wirelessly drag and drop files onto your iOS device.